# Apache2 Allow Users to Connect to IP (Raspberry PI)

Tags: mysql, apache, redirect

I am having some issues with my Apache2 server on my Raspberry Pi.
I have set up a webpage that connects to my MySQL server and displays the data on there.

It works flawlessly on local IP, but I cannot connect to it remotely, for example using my mobile network, or letting someone else test it.

I have set my httpd.conf as following:

```
Listen *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName Raspberry_PI_IP_Here
DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>
```

I have port-forwarded port 80 in my router, and allowed incoming connections to it in my firewall, both TCP and UDP.

I have been searching for days and scouraging videos but nothing works.

What am I doing wrong?

Bump: Still unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

"server offline mode" makes it only connect locally

check if server status is "online"

Comment: Where can I find that?

Comment: my pardon, did you forward port 80 from the router to the local RPi address?

Comment: Yes sir. I ran the "ifconfig" command and used the inet address.

Comment: does it work from other machines linked with the same router?

Comment: from the external device, do you connect to the public ip of the router?

Comment: I connected to the inet address of my RPi.